# Knockout: Clone observable object into another variable and turn it not observable

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I wasn't able to find any answer to this particular question. Suppose I have an observable object that I would like to clone it into another completely independent variable and make this variable not observable. Could someone help me find a solution to this question?

I tried following a solution like this:

```
var notObservableVar = observableVar();
```

But the new variable doesn't appear to be independent since my subsequent code appears to work with observableVar and not a new independent one.

Comment: `var notObservableVar = Object.assign({}, observableVar());`

Comment: Thank you so much, this does appear to work. If you'd like, post a new answer for this question and I will accept the answer as the correct one.

Comment: Please note that this creates a shallow copy. Observable properties of that object will still hold references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update:

As thankfully stated by @Brother Woodrow in the comments, Knockout offers an API method `.toJS()` for the job:

```
var notObservable = ko.toJS(observableVar)
```

> https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

### Old answer (don't use this if your observable object has sub-observables):

To create a shallow copy of an object, you can use`Object.prototype.assign()`:

```
var notObservableVar = Object.assign({}, observableVar());
```

The other option is to use Object destructuring:

```
var notObservableVar = {...observableVar()};
```

Please note that both methods require ES6 support - either in your buildstack (Babel), or in the browser that this is supposed to run in. Also note that for Object destructuring to work with Babel 6, you need a plugin (because Object destructuring was still a proposal when Babel 6 was the current version).

If ES6 is not available for you, you can use the old way of stringifying and then parsing the object:

```
var notObservableVar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(observableVar()));
```

Comment: Is there a possible way of creating a deep copy of the variable instead, to assure that there are no unexpected implications further down when using these variables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Note that Knockout actually has a built-in method `toJS` that does the same thing, but does not rely on `Object.assign`: `var notObservable = ko.toJS(observableVar)`.

Comment: @BrotherWoodrow Does that also affect properties on an observable object which are defined as observables themselves?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the `toJS` method does.